# converting Word File table rowspan into XML using XSLT version 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

I am converting Word File into XML using XSLT version 2.0. How we can get the rowspan attribute in tables.

my xslt code is:

```
<xsl:template match="w:tc">
<xsl:variable name="next-restart" select="parent::w:tr/following-sibling::w:tr[w:tc/w:tcPr/w:vmerge[@w:val='restart']][1]"/>
<xsl:choose>
<td>
<xsl:when test="w:tcPr/w:vmerge[@w:val='restart']">
<xsl:attribute name="morerows">
<xsl:if test="w:tcPr/w:vmerge[@w:val='restart']">
<xsl:value-of select="count(parent::w:tr/following-sibling::w:tr[. &lt;&lt; $next-restart and w:tc/w:tcPr/w:vmerge[not(@w:val)]])"/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</td>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

However this code is not counting all the rows. I need to limit the count to the next `@w:val='restart'`.

my input is:

```
<w:tbl><w:tr><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:vmerge w:val="restart"/></w:tcPr><w:p><w:r><w:t>Interferent</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:gridSpan w:val="2"/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="006E2961" wsp:rsidRPr="006E2961" wsp:rsidRDefault="006E2961" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r wsp:rsidRPr="006E2961"><w:t>Interferent Concentration</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:gridSpan w:val="2"/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="006E2961" wsp:rsidRPr="00DE3782" wsp:rsidRDefault="002A1E40" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>Alanine Aminotransferase Activity</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:gridSpan w:val="2"/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="006E2961" wsp:rsidRPr="00DE3782" wsp:rsidRDefault="006E2961" wsp:rsidP="00F50B9B"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r wsp:rsidRPr="00DE3782"><w:t>Bias</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>*</w:t></w:r><w:r wsp:rsidR="00D34E8A"><w:t>*</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr><w:tr wsp:rsidR="006E2961" wsp:rsidRPr="00DE3782" wsp:rsidTr="00794CE5"><w:trPr><w:trHeight w:val="315"/></w:trPr><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:vmerge/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="006E2961" wsp:rsidRPr="000C1FC9" wsp:rsidRDefault="006E2961" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="006E2961" wsp:rsidRPr="006E2961" wsp:rsidRDefault="006E2961" wsp:rsidP="006E2961"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r wsp:rsidRPr="006E2961"><w:t>Conv. Units</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="006E2961" wsp:rsidRPr="006E2961" wsp:rsidRDefault="006E2961" wsp:rsidP="006E2961"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>SI Units</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="006E2961" wsp:rsidRPr="00DE3782" wsp:rsidRDefault="006E2961" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r wsp:rsidRPr="00DE3782"><w:t>Conv</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>. Units</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p wsp:rsidR="006E2961" wsp:rsidRPr="00DE3782" wsp:rsidRDefault="006E2961" wsp:rsidP="002E7C37"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r wsp:rsidRPr="00DE3782"><w:t>(</w:t></w:r><w:r wsp:rsidR="002E7C37"><w:t>U/L</w:t></w:r><w:r wsp:rsidRPr="00DE3782"><w:t>)</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="006E2961" wsp:rsidRPr="00DE3782" wsp:rsidRDefault="006E2961" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>SI</w:t></w:r><w:r wsp:rsidRPr="00DE3782"><w:t> Units </w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p wsp:rsidR="006E2961" wsp:rsidRPr="00DE3782" wsp:rsidRDefault="006E2961" wsp:rsidP="002E7C37"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r wsp:rsidRPr="00DE3782"><w:t>(</w:t></w:r><w:r wsp:rsidR="009E06EF"><w:t>μ</w:t></w:r><w:r wsp:rsidR="002E7C37"><w:t>kat</w:t></w:r><w:r wsp:rsidRPr="00DE3782"><w:t>/L)</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="006E2961" wsp:rsidRPr="00DE3782" wsp:rsidRDefault="006E2961" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r wsp:rsidRPr="00DE3782"><w:t>Conv</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>. Units</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p wsp:rsidR="006E2961" wsp:rsidRPr="00DE3782" wsp:rsidRDefault="006E2961" wsp:rsidP="002E7C37"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r wsp:rsidRPr="00DE3782"><w:t>(</w:t></w:r><w:r wsp:rsidR="002E7C37"><w:t>U/L</w:t></w:r><w:r wsp:rsidRPr="00DE3782"><w:t>)</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="006E2961" wsp:rsidRPr="00DE3782" wsp:rsidRDefault="006E2961" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>SI </w:t></w:r><w:r wsp:rsidRPr="00DE3782"><w:t> Units </w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p wsp:rsidR="006E2961" wsp:rsidRPr="00DE3782" wsp:rsidRDefault="006E2961" wsp:rsidP="002E7C37"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r wsp:rsidRPr="00DE3782"><w:t>(</w:t></w:r><w:r wsp:rsidR="009E06EF"><w:t>μ</w:t></w:r><w:r wsp:rsidR="002E7C37"><w:t>kat</w:t></w:r><w:r wsp:rsidR="009E06EF" wsp:rsidRPr="00DE3782"><w:t>/L</w:t></w:r><w:r wsp:rsidRPr="00DE3782"><w:t>)</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr><w:tr wsp:rsidR="00606FC6" wsp:rsidRPr="000C1FC9" wsp:rsidTr="00794CE5"><w:trPr><w:trHeight w:val="245"/></w:trPr><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:vmerge w:val="restart"/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="00606FC6" wsp:rsidRPr="000C1FC9" wsp:rsidRDefault="002A1E40" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>Cefoxitin</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="00606FC6" wsp:rsidRPr="006E2961" wsp:rsidRDefault="002A1E40" wsp:rsidP="001D391F"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>333 mg/dL</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="00606FC6" wsp:rsidRPr="006E2961" wsp:rsidRDefault="002A1E40" wsp:rsidP="006E2961"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>7.8 mmol/L</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="001D391F" wsp:rsidRPr="000C1FC9" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="001D391F"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>57</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="00606FC6" wsp:rsidRPr="000C1FC9" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>0.95</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="00606FC6" wsp:rsidRPr="000C1FC9" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>-11</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="00606FC6" wsp:rsidRPr="000C1FC9" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>-0.19</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr><w:tr wsp:rsidR="00606FC6" wsp:rsidRPr="000C1FC9" wsp:rsidTr="00794CE5"><w:trPr><w:trHeight w:val="245"/></w:trPr><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:vmerge/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="00606FC6" wsp:rsidRPr="000C1FC9" wsp:rsidRDefault="00606FC6" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="00606FC6" wsp:rsidRPr="006E2961" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="006E2961"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>167 mg/dL</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="00606FC6" wsp:rsidRPr="006E2961" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="006E2961"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>3.9 mmol/L</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="00606FC6" wsp:rsidRPr="000C1FC9" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>312</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="00606FC6" wsp:rsidRPr="000C1FC9" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>5.21</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="00606FC6" wsp:rsidRPr="000C1FC9" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>-38</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="00606FC6" wsp:rsidRPr="000C1FC9" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="002E7C37"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>-0.64</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr><w:tr wsp:rsidR="009E06EF" wsp:rsidRPr="000C1FC9" wsp:rsidTr="00794CE5"><w:trPr><w:trHeight w:val="245"/></w:trPr><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="009E06EF" wsp:rsidRPr="000C1FC9" wsp:rsidRDefault="002A1E40" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>Hemoglobin</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="009E06EF" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="006E2961"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>1000 mg/dL</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="009E06EF" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="006E2961"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>155 μmol/L</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="009E06EF" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>57</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="009E06EF" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>0.95</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="009E06EF" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>10</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="009E06EF" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>0.16</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr><w:tr wsp:rsidR="002E7C37" wsp:rsidRPr="000C1FC9" wsp:rsidTr="00794CE5"><w:trPr><w:trHeight w:val="245"/></w:trPr><w:tc> <!--Here it is showing the morerows value as '0'--><w:tcPr><w:vmerge w:val="restart"/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="002E7C37" wsp:rsidRPr="000C1FC9" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>Pyruvate</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc> <!--Here it is showing the morerows value as '0'--><w:tcPr><w:vmerge w:val="restart"/><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="002E7C37" wsp:rsidRPr="006E2961" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="006E2961"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>4.4 mg/dL</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc> <!--Here it is showing the morerows value as '0'--><w:tcPr><w:vmerge w:val="restart"/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="002E7C37" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="006E2961"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>0.50 mmol/L</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="002E7C37" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>59</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="002E7C37" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>0.98</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="002E7C37" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>21</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="002E7C37" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>0.36</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr><w:tr wsp:rsidR="002E7C37" wsp:rsidRPr="000C1FC9" wsp:rsidTr="00794CE5"><w:trPr><w:trHeight w:val="245"/></w:trPr><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:vmerge/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="002E7C37" wsp:rsidRPr="000C1FC9" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:vmerge/><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="002E7C37" wsp:rsidRPr="006E2961" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="004F2FC3"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:vmerge/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="002E7C37" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="004F2FC3"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="002E7C37" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="00A67FC4"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>305</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="002E7C37" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>5.09</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="002E7C37" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>35</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="002E7C37" wsp:rsidRDefault="002E7C37" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>0.58</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr><w:tr wsp:rsidR="006A7B37" wsp:rsidRPr="000C1FC9" wsp:rsidTr="00794CE5"><w:trPr><w:trHeight w:val="245"/></w:trPr><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="006A7B37" wsp:rsidRPr="000C1FC9" wsp:rsidRDefault="006A7B37" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>Total Protein</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="006A7B37" wsp:rsidRPr="006E2961" wsp:rsidRDefault="006A7B37" wsp:rsidP="004F2FC3"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>15 g/dL</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="006A7B37" wsp:rsidRDefault="006A7B37" wsp:rsidP="004F2FC3"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>150 g/L</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="006A7B37" wsp:rsidRDefault="006A7B37" wsp:rsidP="00A67FC4"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>310</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="006A7B37" wsp:rsidRDefault="006A7B37" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>5.17</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="006A7B37" wsp:rsidRDefault="006A7B37" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>-34</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:noWrap/><w:vAlign w:val="center"/></w:tcPr><w:p wsp:rsidR="006A7B37" wsp:rsidRDefault="006A7B37" wsp:rsidP="0087625C"><w:pPr><w:jc w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>-0.57</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr></w:tbl>
```

Desire output:

```
<table change.bar="no" frame="all" pgwide="yes" role="test.type.and.conditions"><tgroup cols="7"><colspec colname="col1" colnum="1" colwidth="82.8pt"/><colspec colname="col2" colnum="2" colwidth="54pt"/><colspec colname="col3" colnum="3" colwidth="54pt"/><colspec colname="col4" colnum="4" colwidth="61.2pt"/><colspec colname="col5" colnum="5" colwidth="61.2pt"/><colspec colname="col6" colnum="6" colwidth="55.08pt"/><colspec colname="col7" colnum="7" colwidth="55.08pt"/><thead><row><entry align="center" morerows="1" colname="col1" colsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">Interferent*<table.footnote.ref id="D001"/></para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" namest="col2" nameend="col3" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">Interferent Concentration</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" namest="col4" nameend="col5" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">Alanine Aminotransferase Activity</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" namest="col6" nameend="col7" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">Bias**<table.footnote.ref id="D004"/></para></para.set></entry></row></thead><tbody><row><entry align="center" colname="col2" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">Conv. Units</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col3" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">SI Units</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col4" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">Conv. Units(U/L)</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col5" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">SI Units (μkat/L)</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col6" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">Conv. Units(U/L)</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col7" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">SI  Units (μkat/L)</para></para.set></entry></row><row><entry align="center" morerows="1" colname="col1" colsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">Cefoxitin</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col2" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">333 mg/dL</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col3" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">7.8 mmol/L</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col4" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">57</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col5" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">0.95</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col6" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">-11</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col7" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">-0.19</para></para.set></entry></row><row><entry align="center" colname="col2" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">167 mg/dL</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col3" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">3.9 mmol/L</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col4" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">312</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col5" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">5.21</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col6" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">-38</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col7" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">-0.64</para></para.set></entry></row><row><entry align="center" colname="col1" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">Hemoglobin</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col2" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">1000 mg/dL</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col3" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">155 μmol/L</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col4" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">57</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col5" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">0.95</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col6" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">10</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col7" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">0.16</para></para.set></entry></row><row> <!--there should be the value 1 for all table--><entry align="center" morerows="1" colname="col1" colsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">Pyruvate</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" morerows="1" colname="col2" colsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">4.4 mg/dL</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" morerows="1" colname="col3" colsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">0.50 mmol/L</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col4" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">59</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col5" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">0.98</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col6" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">21</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col7" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">0.36</para></para.set></entry></row><row><entry align="center" colname="col4" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">305</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col5" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">5.09</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col6" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">35</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col7" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">0.58</para></para.set></entry></row><row><entry align="center" colname="col1" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">Total Protein</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col2" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">15 g/dL</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col3" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">150 g/L</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col4" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">310</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col5" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">5.17</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col6" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">-34</para></para.set></entry><entry align="center" colname="col7" colsep="1" rowsep="1" valign="middle"><para.set legal="no"><para change.bar="no" language="en_ww">-0.57</para></para.set></entry></row></tbody></tgroup></table>
```

Comment: Select that node with `@w:val='restart'` in a variable e.g. `<xsl:variable name="next-restart="parent::w:tr/following-sibling::w:tr[w:tc/w:tcPr/w:vMerge[@w:val='restart']'][1]"/>`, then use the `<<` operator in your other predicate e.g. `count(parent::w:tr/following-sibling::w:tr[. << $next-restart and w:tc/w:tcPr/w:vMerge[not(@w:val)]])`. Note that inside of XML/XSLT code you have to escape `<<` as `&lt;&lt;`.

Comment: Hi martin thanks for the help, i have some issues which i describe in the post, could you please help me once again.